# Response of Spark REST API is not comming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark standalone cluster of three nodes(i.e 1 master and 2 slaves)(v2.1.1) .I have created a job and put the job jar in the master machine and whenever want to run the jar i run it through spark submit. But i want to check the status of job by using spark REST API So ,when in browser i am opening http://192.168.1.154:6066/v1/submissions/status/app-20170707165927-0023 .Its response is not coming correctly. I taking submissionId from spark UI.

The response which i am getting is this.

{
  "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "2.1.1",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20170707165927-0023",
  "success" : false
}

[image]

Comment: Use submission-id/driver-id, not app-id. Please see this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958853/apache-spark-how-to-get-app-id-from-submissionid-over-rest-api)