# Apache Spark - How to get app-id from submissionId over Rest API?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to get the progress of an application running at Apache Spark standalone cluster. Is there any way to get the app-id for this pupose over REST API? eg;

```
http://spark-master:6066/v1/submissions/create
```

The response contains a submission id, eg;

```
"submissionId" : "driver-20171222112336-0208"
```

When the status of the driver is requested using that submission id, eg;

```
http://spark-master:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20171222112336-0208
```

The response (after the driver state changed into running) contains Worker Host & Port and a worker id, eg;

```
"workerHostPort": "192.168.1.20:43817",
"workerId": "worker-20170707120806-192.168.1.20-43817"
```

After this progress when the applications listed at that worker, eg;

```
http://192.168.1.20:4040/api/v1/applications
```

This seems to be giving a list of applications (a json array with one element) eg;

```
   [
      {
        "id": "app-20171222112343-0125",
        "name": "test",
        "attempts": [
      ..
```

At this step a list of applications found instead of an app-id and without any information related to driver.

```
http://spark-master:8080/json
```

also gives a list of active applications and again without any information related to drivers, eg;

```
{
    ..
    "activeapps": [..],
    ..
```

So, For a Standalone Apache Spark cluster, how to get application id [app-id] when a job is submitted to the Spark via hidden REST API?

Comment: future request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22970